# Why is the title of this song "Bad"?

Tags: song-title

> If you twist and turn away
>   If you tear yourself in two again
>   If I could, yes I would
>   If I could, I would
>   Let it go
>   Surrender
>   Dislocate
>
> If I could throw this lifeless lifeline to the wind
>   Leave this heart of clay
>   See you walk, walk away
>   Into the night
>   And through the rain
>   Into the half-light
>   And through the flame
>
> If I could through myself
>   Set your spirit free, I'd lead your heart away
>   See you break, break away
>   Into the light
>   And to the day
>
> Ooh, ooh, ooh, ooh
>   Ooh, ooh, ooh, ooh
>   To let it go
>   And so to fade away
>   To let it go
>   And so, fade away
>
> Wide awake
>   I'm wide awake
>   Wide awake
>   I'm not sleeping
>   Oh, no, no, no
>
> If you should ask then maybe they'd
>   Tell you what I would say
>   True colors fly in blue and black
>   Bruised silken sky and burning flag
>   Colors crash, collide in bloodshot eyes
>
> Ooh, ooh, ooh, ooh, ooh, ooh
>   If I could, you know I would, if I could, I would
>   Let it go
>
> This desperation
>   Dislocation
>   Separation, condemnation
>   Revelation in temptation
>   Isolation, desolation
>   Let it go
>
> And so fade away
>   To let it go
>   And so fade away
>   To let it go
>   Oh now, and so to fade away
>
> I'm wide awake
>   I'm wide awake
>   Wide awake
>   I'm not sleeping
>   Oh, no, no, no

This is the song "Bad" written by U2. I think that what they mainly want to say in this song is "I'm wide awake" and "I'm not sleeping". I can't find the part of "bad". Why is the title of this song "Bad"?